# Getting video metadata from a Youtube video

Tags: video, youtube, html5-video

Is there any way to get metadata from youtube video as it is in iframe and embedded. Also- are all youtube videos the same proportion and resolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download youtube videos and/or get the video metadata with [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) (open source)

```
# youtube-dl --list-formats  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yS_iyJGtQg
[youtube] 3yS_iyJGtQg: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 3yS_iyJGtQg: Extracting video information
[youtube] 3yS_iyJGtQg: Downloading DASH manifest
[info] Available formats for 3yS_iyJGtQg:
format code  extension  resolution note
140          m4a        audio only DASH audio  129k , m4a_dash container, aac  @128k (44100Hz), 7.52MiB
278          webm       256x144    DASH video  104k , webm container, VP9, 13fps, video only, 4.95MiB
17           3gp        176x144
36           3gp        320x240
5            flv        400x240
43           webm       640x360
18           mp4        640x360
22           mp4        1280x720   (best)
```